# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 3185]

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Jun  3 01:36:10 2018

@author: Sharad
"""
import numpy as np
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
dbfile=open("D:/df_train_api.pk", 'rb')
df=pickle.load(dbfile)


y=df[['label']]
features=['groups']
X=df[features].copy()
X.columns
y.columns

#for spiliting into training and test data

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=324)
#for vectorizing
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
X_train_counts.shape

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
X_train_tfidf.shape

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
```

The problem lies in the vectorisationg as it gives me X_train_counts of size [1,1]. I don't know why. And that's why MultinomialNB can't perform the action as y_train is of size [1, 3185].
I'm new to machine learning. Any help would be much appreciated.

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-52-5b5949203f76>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Sharad/.spyder-py3/hypothizer.py', wdir='C:/Users/Sharad/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\Sharad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Sharad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Sharad/.spyder-py3/hypothizer.py", line 37, in <module>
    clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)

  File "C:\Users\Sharad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 579, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')

  File "C:\Users\Sharad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 583, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\Sharad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 204, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 3185]
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please include the full traceback. Currently, we don't even know at what line the error occurs, let alone what the context is.

Comment: @9769953   traceback added. please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CountVectorizer (and by inheritence, TfidfTransformer and TfidfVectorizer) expects an iterable of raw documents in `fit()` and [`fit_transform()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform):

> ```
> raw_documents : iterable
>     An iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects.
> ```

So internally it will do this:

```
for doc in raw_documents:
    do_processing(doc)
```

When you pass a pandas DataFrame object in it, only the column names will be yielded by the `for ... in X`. And hence only a single document is processed (instead of data inside that column).

You need to do this:

```
X = df[features].values().ravel()
```

Or else do this:

```
X=df['groups'].copy()
```

There is a difference in the code above and the code you are doing. You are doing this:

```
X=df[features].copy()
```

Here `features` is already a list of columns. So essentially this becomes:

```
X=df[['groups']].copy()
```

The difference is in the double brackets here (which return a dataframe) and single bracket in my code (which returns a Series).

`for value in X` works as expected when X is a series, but only returns column names when X is a dataframe.

Hope this is clear.